# How to maintain a mysql connection between multiple AJAX calls?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, connection

I have a web page using jQuery to perform multiple AJAX calls, not all at once. Each AJAX call is made to a different PHP file, and each file uses a connection to the same mysql server and database.  Creating a connection in each of these AJAX calls is awful for performance, how can I create one connection and maintain it throughout all of the AJAX calls?  Thanks!

Comment: Bad idea. How do you know if there's more calls to come? What if the later AJAX calls are made out of order, or not at all (if the user navigates away or the network drops)?

Comment: not possible. each ajax call is a NEW http request. there is absolutely NO way to guarantee that you'd even get the same thread/helper on the webserver that handled the last request anyways.

Comment: you could cache stuff, but then again php might not be a solution in this problem

Comment: Unless you are connecting to a very remote server (with high latency) there is very little cost to opening a new connection with MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

When running PHP as Apache Module, you can use **persistent connections**. Using the classical (and deprecated) libmysql API, you would call `mysql_pconnect(...)` instead of `mysql_connect(...)`. This triggers PHP not to close MySQL connections after finishing a request and to **reuse this connection for following requests**.

When working with PDO, you can achieve a persistent connection as follows:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass,
  array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

However, usually the performance impact of establishing a connection to the database server should be negligible (I do not have any benchmarks to confirm this, however).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments. It is extremely bad idea.
It might be very tricky when running PHP via apache's mod_php.

> Creating a connection in each of these AJAX calls is awful for performance

Where did this idea came from?
Make sure you are connecting via socket.

Comment: I was under the assumption that connecting to a mysql server used a significant amount of resources, if that's not the case than this entire question is irrelevant as there's really no problem to solve.  Thanks so much!